# Where I can find neo4j-server.properties in Windows 10?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j Community Edition version 3.1.0.
 Does anyone know where i can find neo4j-server.properties in windows 10?
Thank You!

Comment: exe installation or zip installation ... if the latter it's in the conf subdirectory, if the former you should have an tab that shows where the configurations live ...

Answer (score 0):

NO, this conf file is removed in the new neo4j version, all the config items now in "conf/neo4j.conf" file.